use correct .env file while building next.js project
I send CI/CD, dockerfile, next.config.js, and pakcage.json below. The pipeline will successfully pass without any errors and the project starts. But, when on the development branch, it still uses .env.production and not .env.development.
We have tried to dynamically create a .env file based on the branch. But still it prefers .env.production. How can we fix this?
The project is next.js 14 and we use yarn. We have two important branches, development and main and we have .env.production and .env.development
CI/CD file:
stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - backend-blinkship
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build -t <--CONTAINER_NAME--> --build-arg branch=${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH} .
    - DOCKER_TAG=$CI_REGISTRY/customer-portal/frontend/CONTAINER_NAME:$PROJECT_VERSION
    - docker push <--CONTAINER_NAME-->

Dockerfile:
FROM node:20.9.0-alpine as base
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
COPY . /app
ARG branch
RUN if [ "$branch" = "main" ] || [ "$branch" = "master" ]; \
    then cp .env.production /app/.env; \
    else cp .env.development /app/.env; \
    fi
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
EXPOSE 3000


next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {};

const { parsed: localEnv } = require('dotenv').config({
  path: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '.env.production' : '.env.development',
});

module.exports = {
  env: {
  },
};


package.json:
{
  "name": "blink-ship-front-end",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx .",
    "prepare": "husky",
    "format": "prettier-eslint --write $PWD/'**/*.{ts,tsx}'",
    "check-lint": "eslint . --ext ts --ext tsx --ext js",
    "check-types": "tsc --pretty --noEmit",
    "test-all": "npm run check-format && npm run check-lint && npm run check-types && npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^5.3.0",
    "antd": "^5.13.1",
    "antd-img-crop": "^4.21.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "classnames": "^2.5.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "next": "^14.2.2",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.5",
    "nextjs-toploader": "^1.6.11",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "swr": "^2.2.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/nprogress": "^0.2.3",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prettier": "^3.2.4",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}





Normally, Next.js decides automatically (in a specific order), which ".env*" file will be used, depending on the "run mode" (e.g. next dev or next start).

... Next.js allows you to set defaults in .env (all environments), .env.development (development environment), and .env.production (production environment).

So next build will always use .env.production.
Next.js will read the NODE_ENV variable:

If the environment variable NODE_ENV is unassigned, Next.js automatically assigns development when running the next dev command, or production for all other commands.

But setting the NODE_ENV is not recommended, and may cause errors.
You should probably consider the Next.js modes development and production as a different thing than your projects development and production stage.
I.e. you can run both next build (production mode) or next dev (development mode) during your development stage. (You will probably never run next dev in your projects production state, but you could.)
As a solution, you could:

copy different versions (i.e. a "production version" and a "under development version") of the .env.production file depending on your stage (or branch), or
just don't copy the .env.production file, and keep your conditional cp .env.xxx /app/.env .... If there is no other .env.xxx file, then .env will be used.

